# Cannot install my own written kernel driver

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf

I've been working on a kernel-mode driver for Windows 10 using `Visual Studio 2015`. I can install my driver on VM (which has the exact same version of Windows that I've installed on my host computer) using Visual Studio run and it works just fine. Now I want to install it on the host PC (the primary Windows). First of all, I enabled Test Signing on it. I right clicked on driver `inf` file and selected Install. It asked if I was sure and I clicked on `Yes`. After a few seconds a dialog box is shown saying `The operation completed successfully.` but in fact nothing happens.

- It's not being shown in Device Manager on host computer while it is on test computer.
- No debug message appears in DebugView related to my driver.
- NOTHING is written in `setupact.log`

I'm using `release for x64` configuration. I wonder if there's anything I'm missing in the project config.
I also tried restarting my PC after installation, but it's not working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What `net start <driverservice>` tells you? Did you try to disable Secure Boot (an additional driver signing requirement is planned in the Anniversary Update, however, I am not sure whether it is really in effect).

Comment: @MartinDrab: I think I can't use that command when the driver is not installed yet. I tried it though and it says the service couldn't be found. No I'll try disabling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is really odd.

I was using a standard class provided by Microsoft called "SoftwareDevice" and I could install the driver on my Test computer only using `Visual Studio Remote Kernel Debugger`. However, I had to register and use a custom class and then I could successfully install the driver.